# load_textdomain won't load my .mo file

Tags: templates, translation, sitemap

I am using Yoast' method to build an HTML site map. But it needs to be translated.

It uses a page template page-sitemap.php that uses a template part

```
<?php get_template_part('/partials/sitemap');  ?>
```

In this template part I...

```
load_textdomain( 'site-map', TEMPLATEPATH.'/partials/languages' );
```

The path is right for I list the files of the folder TEMPLATEPATH.'/partials/languages' and it shows my language files.

As you see my domain name is 'site-map'. My `.mo` file is `site-map-fr_FR.mo`.

Why can't it be loaded?

Thanks for any clue,
nicolas

Comment: Try [Debug Translations](http://marketpress.com/product/debug-translations/). Do you get any useful output?

Comment: `load_textdomain` returns boolean value. Can you check what it returns in your case?

Comment: thanks for your answers, @Chittaranjan : It return false ! (sorry i forgot to mention this important point.)

Comment: @Toscho : i go for the plugin, I didn't it ! :)

Comment: So either the mo file is not readable or the import fails. Check here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_textdomain

Comment: Thanks Chittaranjan, yes i checked this page already. readable : the chmod lets everybody read. But why would the import fail ? I find no ressource about this. I could modifie load_textdomaine function temporarily to display more info about the cause of this problem ...

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer: `load_textdomain( 'site-map', TEMPLATEPATH.'/partials/languages' );` ... gives the path of the folder containing the .mo file. but the path of every individual mo file should be used in its own `load_textdomain` instruction :

```
load_textdomain('site-map', TEMPLATEPATH.'/partials/languages/site-map-fr_FR.mo'); 
load_textdomain('site-map', TEMPLATEPATH.'/partials/languages/site-map-en_US.mo'); 
load_textdomain('site-map', TEMPLATEPATH.'/partials/languages/site-map-es_ES.mo'); 
load_textdomain('site-map', TEMPLATEPATH.'/partials/languages/site-map-ru_RU.mo'); 
load_textdomain('site-map', TEMPLATEPATH.'/partials/languages/site-map-de_DE.mo');
```

Shame on me it is a very obvious and useless thread ... Sorry!

Comment: this is obviously wrong, as wordpress is supposed to find the relevant file based on the "current" locale. You are not supposed to find the right file by yourself